# Difference between browser.wait() and setTimeOut() function

Tags: angular, asynchronous, protractor, event-handling, e2e-testing

I am working on test automation and using Protractor for this purpose. 
Basically, I have two questions

1) What is the difference between `browser.wait()` and `setTimeout()` function. Which one is better? 
2) Whether `browser.wait()` waits until the promise resolves or until the time given is out?
My English is not much better, hope you will understand what I am trying to say. 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`setTimeout()` is a JS function to use when you need you execute something after the *timer* expires.

`browser.wait()` is a Protractor command; It doesn't affect the JS runtime, it just blocks the weddriver's control flow. It will only delay future webdriver commands from being executed (as per Protractor's API)

Comment: Thanks for sharing, helped to identify some weird jasmine time out issues.